# Reset the counter when column has non zero value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe with a column.

```
  A   
  0.0
  0.0
  0.0
  12.0
  0.0
  0.0
  34.0
  0.0
  0.0
  0.0
  0.0
  11.0
```

I want the output like this with a counter column. I want the counter to be restarted after non zero value. For the row after every non zero value, the counter should be intilaized again and then should increment.

```
 A   Counter

 0.0   1
 0.0   2
 0.0   3
 12.0  4
 0.0   1
 0.0   2
 34.0  3
 0.0   1
 0.0   2
 0.0   3
 0.0   4
 11.0  5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `cumsum` create the `groupby` key , `[::-1]` here is reverse the order

```
df['Counter'] = df.A.groupby(df.A.ne(0)[::-1].cumsum()).cumcount()+1
Out[442]: 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     1
8     2
9     3
10    4
11    5
dtype: int64
```